# MySql conditional stop script execution

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-scripts

I need to write SQL script which stops if some values not found in DB.
Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
BEGIN;
...
set @a = (select ... );
if @a IS NULL THEN STOP_WITH_ERROR_AND_ROLLBACK();
...
COMMIT;
```

Can anybody help to me?

**UPDATE:** for some reasons, I can't use stored procedures or functions.

**UPDATE 2:** Note: I don't need explicit rollback. Break of script execution are sufficiently. It automatically rollback changes of not-committed transaction.

Comment: MySQL allows you to declare error handlers WITHIN a stored program (e.g. `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND...`; see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html) which can execute a specific code you may need before exiting. You are saying that you cannot use a stored procedure/function. Could you explain why?

Comment: I write script, which our DB administrator will use for edit of our DB. As rule, script runs from remote machine, but for security reasons, changing and/or creating stored procedures from remote connections disabled at our MySql Server.
Note: I don't need explicit rollback. Break of script execution are sufficiently. It automatically rollback changes of not-committed transaction.

Comment: Does the solution posted by Kumar work?

Comment: No. It don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    start transaction;

    set @a=(select ...);
     -- whatever you want to execute your code like insert, update

    set @b=(select if(@a is null,'ROLLBACK','COMMIT'));
    -- @b is store **ROLLBACK** if @a is null nither store **COMMIT**

    prepare statement1 from @b;
    -- now statement1 store as @a value
    execute statement1;
```

i hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you going. Do some research on how to use transaction is mySQL.

```
START TRANSACTION
...
set @a = (select ... );
IF @a IS NULL 
THEN
 SELECT 'Error Message' as ErrorMsg
 ROLLBACK;
END IF;
...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: If  I'm not mistake, the "IF" statement can be used only  for stored procedures. I get error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @CplxSecDirHdrId IS NULL  THEN  SELECT 'Error Message' as ErrorMsg  ROLLBACK' at line 2"

Comment: Check for the syntax. might have missed something.

Comment: This simple script got a error: 
use test;
START TRANSACTION;
set @a = (select 1);
IF @a IS NULL 
THEN
 SELECT 'Error Message' as ErrorMsg
 ROLLBACK;
END IF;
COMMIT;